# Perl: threads vs JSON

Tags: json, multithreading, perl

Below listed program fails with the following error:

```
JSON text must be an object or array (but found number, string, true, false or null, use allow_nonref to allow this) at json_test.pl line 10.
```

Works fine when I comment out thread startup/join, or when JSON is parsed before thread is run.
Message seems to be coming from JSON library, so I suppose something is wrong with it.
Any ideas what's going on and how to fix it?

```
# json_test.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $t = threads->new(\&DoSomething);
my $str = '{"category":"dummy"}';
my $json = JSON->new();
my $data = $json->decode($str);
print Dumper($data);
$t->join();

sub DoSomething
{
    sleep 10;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Works for me with [JSON::PP](http://p3rl.org/JSON::PP), [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::XS), and [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/Cpanel::JSON::XS). What version of Perl and of the JSON library do you use?

Comment: Perl 5.24.0
Module id = JSON::XS
    INST_VERSION 3.02
Module id = JSON::PP
    INST_VERSION 2.27400
Module id = Cpanel::JSON::XS
    INST_VERSION 3.0213
I

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON uses JSON::XS if installed which is [not compatible with Perl threads](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#(I-)THREADS) (please don't take the author's words at face value - threads are discouraged and difficult to use effectively, but not deprecated and there are no plans to remove them). The community-preferred fork Cpanel::JSON::XS [is thread safe](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS#cPanel-fork) and will be used by [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) by default, which is a mostly drop-in replacement for JSON.